# Can commercial organisations use CiviCRM

Tags: user-account

Your website states that you are a CRM system for non-profits. As an open source setup, can commercial entities and freelancers use your platform?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can be used by whoever wishes to make use of it. It is largely used by NGOs but there are many commercial entities using it for their own requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As @petednz stated commercial organizations can use CiviCRM. You will find where most of the commercial CRM's are focused on the customer/supplier relationships, accounts and leads CiviCRM is based on individuals, organizations and households and their relationships.